# How to execute an executable from Linux with javascript

Tags: javascript, linux, activex, shellexecute

I'm making an application for D-bus in javascript. I need to call an executable from the javascript code and I know that it's possible to do it in Windows like this

```
var activeXObj = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application"); 
activeXObj.ShellExecute("C:\\WINDOWS\\NOTEPAD.EXE", "", "", "open", "1");
```

But...how to do the same in Linux??

Thanks a lot

P.S: Is not for a browser =)

Comment: There is no way. Browsers (maybe except IE) are designed not to touch the user's machine for security reasons. Plugins could do it, but with limited reach also.

Comment: From the original question I'm not sure the script is really intended to be used inside a browser. I am sure however that it cannot be done with activex on linux.

Comment: It's not for a browser =)

Answer (score 1):

Install node.js (depending on your distro, `sudo apt-get install nodejs`) and use the [ChildProcess](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) module to execute the program.

Or, get [Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rhino) and use the [runCommand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rhino/Shell#runCommand) command;