# Opening .java files in Eclipse from a Browser

Tags: java, eclipse, url, browser

For debugging reasons, we have a tool that displays our component tree structure in a web page, this contains hundreds of different classes.

What i would like to do is to generate a hyperlink to automatically open the java class in eclipse from the browser (i.e something like:   `<a href="eclipse://com.java.util.ArrayList#"removeAll,Collection">` ).

Is it possible to configure eclipse to open a specific Java class at a specific method from a browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open file in eclipse with command line option [refer here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/OpenFileFeature). But you can't jump to any functions and to any given line number [see bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=305336).

---

If you just want to open file in eclipse(regardless of location):

---

Call the command(explained in first link) via Javascript. Refer [How can I run a program or batch file on the client side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877774/how-can-i-run-a-program-or-batch-file-on-the-client-side) and [How to execute an executable from Linux with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16607782/how-to-execute-an-executable-from-linux-with-javascript) but I am not sure whether is works and depends on OS and/or browser.

---

You can open Java file in browser itself with syntax highlighting:

---

Refer [Code Mirror](http://codemirror.net/) and [ACE](http://ace.c9.io/#nav=about), [FileReader and CodeMirror Load File Complication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17646555/filereader-and-codemirror-load-file-complication), [Loading .txt file into textarea Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19020484/loading-txt-file-into-textarea-javascript).

Comment: Thank you Chandrayya, for URL side i would configure a protocol, but for the eclipse side i have raised bug 452087.